# ASP.NET Core 3.1 API Ocelot JWT Returns 401 on Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I'm trying to implement the microservice architecture. I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 API to implement.

I installed jwt packages ocelot and auth servers. When I try to log in, it returns 401. So, this part of my application is wrong. What is wrong with my code? These are my codes;

**ocelot.json**

I added the AuthenticationOptions key to the ocelot file.

```json
"Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/auth/{path}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 52150
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/identity/{path}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "Get",
        "Post",
        "Put",
        "Delete"
      ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "MY_SECRET_KEY",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }
    }
  ]
```

**API Gateway Startup.cs**

I implement jwt for api gateway

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var jwtConfig = Configuration.GetSection("JWT");
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtConfig["Secret"]));
            string providerKey = "MY_SECRET_KEY";

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtConfig["Issuer"],
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtConfig["Audience"],
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = providerKey;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddJwtBearer(providerKey, config =>
                    {
                        config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        config.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                    });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
            //services.AddControllers();
        }

public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();

            await app.UseOcelot();
            

            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    //endpoints.MapControllers();
            //});
        }
```

**Auth Server Startup.cs**

After, I set up JWT for my auth server.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var jwtConfig = Configuration.GetSection("JWT");
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtConfig["Secret"]));
            string providerKey = "MY_SECRET_KEY";

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtConfig["Issuer"],
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtConfig["Audience"],
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = providerKey;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddJwtBearer(providerKey, config =>
                    {
                        config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        config.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                    });

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

**AuthController's LoginAsync Action**

I can't even send requests here.

```cs
 [HttpPost("login")]
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromForm] Login model)
        {
            var result = await authService.LoginAsync(model);

            if (result.Response.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
        }
```

This is the screenshot for the response;

[image: Example screenshot]

I don't understand why I'm getting 401?

Comment: Is the authentication working if you call the API directly? We must get this working in order to understand if the problem is coming from the API project or the API gateway implementation

Comment: @Krusty yes it works when I call the API directly.

Comment: I reccomend to use Fiddler to understand how the request is currently forwarded by Ocelot. At least to understand if the JWT token is present or not in the request body.

Comment: @Krusty thanks. I'll check and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
```

Change your code like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(providerKey ,option =>
        {
            option.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            option.SaveToken = true;
            option.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters ;

        });
```